# wordpress button not working while link works

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, button

I apologize for the simplicity of the question, I am definitely still a beginner.

For some reason the following link works:

```
<a id="header-log-in" href="<?php echo get_permalink( 39 ); ?>">Log In</a>
```

However, the following button does not work:

```
<form action="<?php echo the_permalink( 39 ); ?>">
        <input type="submit" id="header-create-acct" value="Sign Up" />
</form>
```

All help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: your names for the two are different. One is called "get_permalink( 39 );" and the other is "the_permalink( 39 );" without seeing your php code I would start there

Comment: @Ryan Beaulieu the_permalink() and get_permalink() both are WordPress native functions . the_permalink() is used to get current post permalink inside loop .. and get_permalink() takes optional post id as argument . and returns link of that post.

Comment: Does it show page 39's URL in teh source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this .

```
<form method='post' action="<?php echo get_page_link(39); ?>">
        <input type="submit" id="header-create-acct" value="Sign Up" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using [`the_permalink()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_permalink) in the second, which **must** be use within The Loop - it does not take a post ID as an argument. If you want to return the value of the link, you should use [`get_permalink( $post_id )`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_permalink) as in the first example - which does take a `$post_id` argument - and then `echo` the result so that it prints out within the `action` attribute of your `form`.

```
<form action="<?php echo get_permalink( 39 ); ?>">
        <input type="submit" id="header-create-acct" value="Sign Up" />
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. However: <form action="<?php echo get_permalink( 39 ); ?>"> still does not work

Comment: Can you give more details about what isn't working? The `get_permalink()` function should work for posts and pages.

Comment: sure, basically when I press the button, I just get redirected from localhost/wordpress to localhost/wordpress/?

Comment: When you view the source, is the action attribute empty?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the parameter from the function

```
<form action="<?php echo the_permalink(); ?>">
        <input type="submit" id="header-create-acct" value="Sign Up" />
</form>
```

From [WordPress Manual](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_permalink) : 
This tag has no parameters.